# Can i connect notion page to Integration key only with code?

Tags: notion-api

I want to make application that makes a new page in Notion, makes a database in there and stores values in it.
So I'm reading out Notion api Ref , but cannot fully understand it

What I wonder is...

1. Is the return value of 'create a token' endpoint same as Integration key?
2. Is it possible to make a new page and connect it to Integration key only with code?

For now, i made my app to make a DB and store values in the environment that Notion Integration key and PageId is provided and the page is linked with Integration key.

So i want to make the environment Things to act automatically.